# Android Local app opens in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm developing an app that should display a web page and from a link in that page open another app, let's call it **otherApp**. I display the web page in my app with WebView;

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().indexOf("example")>0) {
           // This is my web site, so do not override;                  
           //let my WebView load the page
           return false;
       }
       // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch
       // another Activity that handles URLs
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
       startActivity(intent);
       return true;
   }
});
myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com/demo.html");
```

The demo.html file contains the link:

```
<a href="otherapp://"> Start otherApp </a>
```

Using the tablet's browser, clicking the link opens **otherApp** as expected with Chrome still running.  However when using my app, **otherApp** opens in WebView and I need both apps to be running independently of each other. The code was taken from developer.android.com, I'm using a Nexus 7 tablet running Marshmallow.

Any ideas what I am missing?